# how to Authenticate login using Login, password and OpenSSL certificate?

Tags: php, authentication, openssl

I have Php based Application. which works perfect with login and password. Now i want to implement authenticate using OpenSSL along with login and password.

I have generated the OpenSSL in Linux server and i have to use the generated openSSL.cert file as certificated. I installed that in my browser and my DNS is set with https so it should promte for certificate,

Now what i need is, When somebody tries to login wihtout certificate it should not now allow to login. I should check the certificated to authenticate the login.

Is they any way to do this or am i being more ambitious ?
if yes, How can i do this i php ?

Thanks all.

Comment: its your server you need to configure not php .... what server are you using ???

Comment: its linux server, with php and apache on it.

Answer (score 0):

SSL uses Diffie-Hellman (or similar) key exchange to negotiate a connection meaning that the certificate is provided to any client that does not already have it. What you want to do is probably best done by using a license key file. Were I doing it I should create a hashed key using something company specific that only I knew and have the string passed across to authenticate. The benefit of it over preventing key exchange in SSL and sending out certificates is that the hashed string is easier to create on a per client basis. This means that you can uniquely identify a client easily and give specific limitation, such as an expiry time, by client.